# How to show the back button on the particular page in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I have added a back button in my toolbar and I want to show the back button only on some particular pages.

This is **app.component.html**:

```
<ion-back-button class="btnmy11" defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
```

I want to show the back button only on some particular pages.

I have added the CSS for displaying the back button on some particular pages but it is not working.

I have also added the `[hidden]="menuIsHidden"` and make it false by default and true on some particular pages but this is also not working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @PeterHaddad. I am using the common header and I have added it only in app.component.ts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a page by executing the following command:

```
ionic generate page SharedToolbar
```

Then inside that page use the `@Input()` directive, example:

**html:**

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
 <ion-buttons slot="start">
  <div *ngIf="showBackButton== 'true'">
  <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
  </div>
</ion-buttons>
```

**typescript:**

```
@Component({
 selector    : 'shared-toolbar',
 templateUrl : './shared-toolbar.page.html',
 styleUrls   : ['./shared-toolbar.page.scss'],
 })
export class SharedToolbar implements OnInit 
{
  @Input() showBackButton: string  = 'false';
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(){}
}
```

Then in any page you create, you can add the following in the html:

```
<shared-toolbar showBackButton="true"></shared-toolbar>
```

and send the following attribute as above to show the back button.

**Note:**

In the module of each page you might have to add the following:

```
  schemas : [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
```

to be able to use a template URL of a specific page.

more info here:

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#pass-values-into-the-directive-with-an-input-data-binding

Comment: But the problem is that I have common header. and the back button is in header that is in app.component.html.

Comment: yes u remove the header from there and added in this sharedtoolbar

Comment: Can you tell me where to add schemas?

Comment: in the module.ts of the sharedtoolbar class

Comment: under the `declartion array` inside the `@ngmodule`

Comment: Okay After declarations or in the declarations.

Comment: in the module u have a declaration array that contains the page name, under the declaration array.. yes after...

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a css class such as:

```
.back-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

And then use a `ngClass` on the back button that applies the style if needed.

```
<ion-back-button class="btnmy11" defaultHref="/" [ngClass]="{'back-hide': menuIsHidden==true}"></ion-back-button>
```

Comment: This back button is in app.component.ts and if I added the css in my particular page, it is not working.

Comment: And By default I want to back button hidden.

Comment: Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

where you want to show back button you can use `ion-nav` instead use of `ion-toolbar`.
By default `ion-nav` animates transition between pages based in the mode (ios or material design).